# Ruby on Rails wildcard routing such as /foo.htm /foo.php /foo.something

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to create a routing situation where by default, any URL's such as this:

/foo

/something

/foo.php

/somethingelse.xml

/something.something.else

etc.

will all route to one controller, assuming they don't route anywhere else.

i can get this to work with the following code in my routes:

map.myroute '/:file_or_folder', :controller => 'mycontroller'

this works fine as long as there are no dots in the URL:

/something

but this wont work:

/something.foo

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dots are not allowed by default.   You can specify a regex for what file_or_folder can match, such as this:

```
map.myroute '/:file_or_folder', :controller => 'mycontroller', :file_or_folder => /.*/
```

Comment: Thanks that did it!  Yay StackOverflow!